# MVVM: delegating PropertyChanged notifications A -> B (readonly) -> C

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui, inotifypropertychanged, community-toolkit-mvvm

In a .NET MAUI application I am using the Mvvm.CommunityToolkit with source generation capabiliities for INotifyPropertyChanged support in my ViewModels:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty

Now I am facing a design challenge.
Sticking with the example:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(FullName))]
private string? firstName;

[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(FullName))]
private string? lastName;


public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
```

This is all well and good, `FullName` will get updated when it is bound in the UI, etc.

Now what do I do if I have another property that needs to update whenever `FullName` gets updated?

Take this (admittedly contrived) example (I want to keep this very simple, the practical application is given at the end):

```cs
public int NumberOfXsInName => FullName.Count(x => char.ToLower(x) == 'x');
```

How can I get that notification?
I do not want to add `[NotifyPropertyChangedFor]` to all properties that notify FullName, since that seems not very resilient, especially since I can not enforce that subclasses will do that correctly.

Do I have to write in the constructor of my ViewModel

```cs
PropertyChanged += (_, e) =>
{
    if (e?.PropertyName?.Equals(nameof(FullName)) ?? false)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NumberOfXsInFullName));
    }
};
```

This seems very verbose for just wanting to "chain up" the PropertyChanged notification through a read-only property (since I can not raise it in a setter)

(*) In practice, I want to split a FilteredCollection, that is based on a DataSource and a FilterFunction, into Groups. Here, the FilteredCollection is just a readonly property that gets notified (like FullName in the example), and I want to split this into two groups based on some criteria for consumption in a different view.

Comment: have you tried using `[DependsOn]` instead?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean, where would I find this annotation? It does not seem to be part of the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm API ?

Comment: sorry, I assumed it was in CommunityToolkit, we actually get ours from the Fody PropertyChanged nuget

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro unfortunately not, haven’t looked in a while, though

Answer (score 0):

**new post #1**

I would suggest going back to basics and using something like the following:

```
public class Class1: ObservableObject
{
    private string lastName;
    private string firstName;
    private string fullName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get => firstName;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref firstName, value);
            UpdateFullName();
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get => lastName;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref lastName, value);
            UpdateFullName();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateFullName()
    {
        FullName = $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get => fullName;
        private set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref fullName, value))
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NumberOfXsInName));
            }
        }
    }

    public int NumberOfXsInName => FullName.Count(x => char.ToLower(x) == 'x');
}
```

**Original post with code that does not work as intended but has been retained due to comment 1 by @HotteMax**

As

```
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(FullName))]
private string? firstName;
```

expands to

```
public string? FirstName
{
    get => firstName;
    set
    {
        if (SetProperty(ref firstName, value))
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }
}
```

I guess that you could have something like the following (sticking with the tool kit)

```
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(NotifyFullNameDependents))]
private string? firstName;

[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(NotifyFullNameDependents))]
private string? lastName;

[RelayCommand]
private void NotifyFullNameDependents()
{
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NumberOfXsInName));    
}

public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

public int NumberOfXsInName => FullName.Count(x => char.ToLower(x) == 'x');
```

but this would leave a public `IRelayCommand` property.

Comment: Hmm, no, that merely sets the CanExecuteChanged status, it does not "run" the command. Anyway, I dont want a RelayCommand just for propagating around PropertyChanged events ...

Comment: @Hottemax Thank you for checking. I don't think that you can use the Toolkit in the way that you want' I've updated my answer to include a potential work around